# Resolve circular dependency with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I have three classes which implement their interface.

Orders

```
public interface IOrderService
{
   //SomeOrderFunction()
}

public class OrderService: IOrderService
{
    //SomeOrderFunction();
}
```

Drivers

```
public interface IDriverService
{
   //SomeDriverFunction()
}

public class DriverService: IDriverService
{
    //SomeDriverFunction();
}
```

Plans -- Uses Driver and Plan services

```
public interface IPlanService
{
   //SomePlanFunction()
}

public class PlanService: IPlanService
{
    private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
    private readonly IDriverService _driverService;

    public PlanService(IDriverService driverService, IOrderService orderService)
    {
      _orderService = orderService;
      _driverService = driverService;
    }

    //PlanFunctionsThatUseServices();
}
```

The issue I now have though is that the Order and Driver service need to talk back to the plan service when either an Order or Driver gets changed, how would I go about doing this without having a circular dependency?

**Edit**:
Specifically I've been looking at creating a fourth service that manages all the other ones such as the one explained in this article.

[Breaking Dependency Cycles](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/07/17/breaking-dependency-cylces/)

What confuses me about this implementation is my Plan class, does my plan class implement both the new class AND the IPlan interface?

Comment: I dont think it is possible without having this reference. Alternatively, you can create _fourth_ class that manages communication between the three  services.

Answer (score 6):

via events.

create an event handler interface:

```
public interface IEventSubscriber<TEvent>
{
    void Handle(TEvent evt);
}
```

then define an event:

```
public class PlanCreated
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    //and other properties.
}
```

Now let one of the other classes implement it:

```
public class DriverService : IDriverService, IEventSubscriber<PlanCreated>
{
    public void Handle(PlanCreated evt)
    {
        //handle it here.
    }
}
```

now, to be able to publish events you need another interface:

```
public interface IEventPublisher
{
    void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent evt);
}
```

Which can be invoked from your class:

```
public class PlanService: IPlanService
{
    private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
    private readonly IDriverService _driverService;

    public PlanService(IDriverService driverService, IOrderService orderService, IEventPublisher publisher)
    {
      _orderService = orderService;
      _driverService = driverService;
    }

    public void PlanFunctionsThatUseServices()
    {

       //business code....


      _publisher.Publish(new PlanCreated(){ Id = plan.Id } );
}
```

.. to invoke it we can use service location (implementation detail):

```
public class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
{

    public EventPublisher(YourFavoriteContainer container)
    {
    }


    public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent evt)
    {
        using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var handlers = scope.ResolveAll<IEventSubscriber<TEvent>>();
            foreach (var handler in handlers)
            {
                //TODO: Handle exceptions=
                handler.Handle(evt);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

.. as a result you get low coupling between the classes.

Comment: It could be fair to mention that this approach is a well known pattern called the Event Aggregator. This gives the OP a chance to find more information on their own.

Comment: I don't think so. Event Aggregator is to Channel events from multiple objects ***into a single object*** to simplify registration for clients. The pattern is more about handling events for multiple instances of the same object type.

Answer (score 3):

Inject a `Func<IPlanService>` instead of the `IPlanService` into the `IOrderService` and `IDriverService`. This 'breaks' the chain of instances that the container has to create.

```
public class OrderService {
    public OrderService(Func<IPlanService> planServiceFactory) {
        _planServiceFactory = planServiceFactory;
    }

    private readonly Func<IPlanService> _planServiceFactory;

    public void SomeOrderFunction() {
        _planServiceFactory().Notify(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, rethink your approach.

Second, if you still insist on having a circular dependency, you could make it less explicit by making the dependent service responsible for setting the backward dependency, e.g.

```
public interface IOrderService
{
   //SomeOrderFunction()
   IPlanService planService;
}

....

public class PlanService: IPlanService
{
   private readonly IOrderService _orderService;

   public PlanService(IOrderService orderService)
   {
      _orderService = orderService;
      _orderService.planService = this;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried thinking about a different approach, but in the end the plan needs to be advised that either order or driver has been changed. 

What do you think about this approach, having a main node that knows all of the services. http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/07/17/breaking-dependency-cylces/

Comment: imho this is more of a workaround and it also introduces temporal coupling.